# Statistical Test - Multiple Reviews of the Same Sample

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I work in a field that assess applications for benefit. We are interested in comparing outcomes between client groups to identify potential bias. We plan to anonymizing applications to remove factors that might identify the client as belonging to either client group and have decision-makers review them to compare outcomes. Anonymizing applications is resource intensive so we intend to perform the test on a a small sample (20 per client group). The idea was originally to have one decision-maker do the review and perform an unpaired T-test on the results. To correct for high variability among decision-makers, having multiple decision-makers review the same sample has been proposed. The lack of independence in one dimension of the sample seems to rule out both a T and Chi-Square test.

Is there a statistical in such a scenario? Thank you.

Comment: It seems there are a lot of unknowns here, which makes it hard to say much.  For instance, you appear to be assuming that anonymizing the clients doesn't introduce a bias, but that could be false.  A priori, it's possible that membership in one group or another is correlated to the thing you are measuring so if you anonymize too much you'll lose access to a key variable.  And high variability among decision makers is troubling...what causes that?  Again, why shouldn't one worry that that variability is correlated to thing you are trying to measure?

Comment: All of which is to say that it seems to me that more modeling is needed here.  I don't see a quick short cut.

Comment: Thank you very much for your questions. The thing we're trying to measure is the relative influence of group membership (which is a factor) versus the other factors that are considered by decision-makers. The reason outcomes vary between decision-makers is that the criteria leave a lot to the judgement / discretion of the decision-makers. There are good reasons to believe variability among decision-makers correlates with group membership - another reason to use more than one. Does that context help?